# Js / Php - I cant open a file with ssh

Tags: php, file-exists

So here I am, I have a problem in my code. I need your help

The context: the user clicks on the download button, this passes in http parameter the name of the files to download and in my php page depending on whether the file exists, the user can download it.

[Exemple of context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCjJq.png)

The problem: No matter which file I use the problem remains the same, in my php, I always pass in the if, which is that my file does not exist.

```
if (!file_exists($fileName))
```

I tried with Putty to download my file and its working, so it comes from my code. If you have an idea or documentations to help me, it would be very appreciate.

If you find my request not clear, tell me that I help you understand

The js :

```
$( ".js-img-download" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        var currow = $(this).closest('tr');
        var idevt = currow.find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var nomfic = currow.find('td:eq(2)').text();
        var statevt = currow.find('td:eq(3)').text();
        if (idevt == '80209' && statevt == '70003'){
            var filename = '//Talend/PEC_DF6/FluxSortantResultatPEC/ARCHIVES/AR/' + nomfic;
            alert(filename);
        }
        else if (idevt == '80209' && statevt == '70002'){
            var filename = '//Talend/PEC_DF6/FluxSortantResultatPEC/ARCHIVES/XML/' + nomfic;
            alert(filename);  
        }
        else if (idevt == '80205' && statevt == '70003'){
            var filename = '//Talend/PEC_DF6/FluxSortantAdmissionPEC/ARCHIVES/AR/' + nomfic;
            alert(filename);
        }
        else if (idevt == '80205' && statevt == '70002'){
            var filename = '//Talend/PEC_DF6/FluxSortantAdmissionPEC/ARCHIVES/XML/' + nomfic;
            alert(filename);
        }
        else if (idevt == '80205' && statevt == '70006'){
            var filename = '//Talend/PEC_DF6/FluxSortantAdmissionPEC/ARCHIVES/XML/' + nomfic;
            alert(filename);
        }
        else if (idevt == '80201' && statevt == '70002'){
            var filename = '//Talend/PEC_DF1/PRD01_IntegrationDeclaratif/ARCHIVES/AR_TECH/' + nomfic;
            alert(filename);
        }
        else if (idevt == '80201' && statevt == '70005'){
            var filename = '//Talend/PEC_DF1/PRD01_IntegrationDeclaratif/ARCHIVES/DRP/XML/' + nomfic;
            alert(filename);
        }
        // Ajax permettant d'envoyer le nom du fichier a télécharger au serveur
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/supervision/admin/ajaxdownloadfile',
            async : true,
            data : {
                filename : filename
            },
            success : function() {
              window.location.href = '/supervision/admin/ajaxdownloadfile?name=' + filename;
            }  
        });
    });
    $(this).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    });
});
```

The php :

```
 $connection = ssh2_connect($this->_configFile->ftp->hostname, $this->_configFile->ftp->port);
        if ($connection) {
            $login = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->_configFile->ftp->login, $this->_configFile->ftp->password);
            if ($login) {
                $content = true;
                if ($content) { 
                    $fileName = $this->_getParam('name');
                    echo $fileName;
                    if (!file_exists($fileName)){ 
                        header('Refresh:3; url=/supervision/admin/suivifluxtechnique');
                        echo "ERROR 404";
                        echo "</br>";
                        echo "Le fichier n&apos;existe pas ou &agrave; &eacute;t&eacute; d&eacute;plac&eacute;";
                    }
                    else{
                        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'cat'.$fileName);
                        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                        $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
                        simplexml_load_string($output); 
                        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($output);
                        $abc = htmlentities($xml->asXML());

                        $file = $abc; 

                        header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
                        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
                        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file)); 

                        readfile ($file);
                        exit(); 
                    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSH or JavaScript. Print out `$fileName` before `file_exists()` then check if the full path is correct. Make sure you use full absolute paths.

Comment: I have maybe an idea about the problem. when connecting to my ssh server, the server connects to a precise folder, when I am on putty I have to do twice "cd .." then put my "cd path". but in my code there is no "cd ..", the problem can be from there no?